# Exclude / Not equal multiple values in wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have modified a Wordpress query.

I need to exclude three values but cannot figure out how to do it. I have read lots of people passing more than one value to match but not to exclude. I have tried several things across several hours.

```
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => '12', 
'cat' => $cat_id,
'posts_type' => 'post',
'paged' => $paged, 
'meta_key' => 'post_price', 
'meta_value' =>'SWAP', 'FREE', 'WANTED',
'meta_compare' => '!=',
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working, heres the code I used in case anyone is interested

```
    $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => '12', 
                        'cat' => $cat_id,
                        'posts_type' => 'post',
                        'paged' => $paged, 
                        'meta_key' => 'post_price', 
                        'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'post_price', 
        'value' => 'SWAP',
        'compare' => '!='

    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'post_price', 
        'value' => 'FREE',
        'compare' => '!='

    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'post_price', 
        'value' => 'WANTED',
        'compare' => '!='

    )
    ),
    ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue here:

```
'meta_value' =>'SWAP', 'FREE', 'WANTED',
```

In this case `meta_value` is set to `SWAP`. `FREE` and `WANTED` are just separate entries in the array. Writing your code out like this reveals the problem:

```
array( 
    'posts_per_page' => '12', 
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'posts_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'meta_key' => 'post_price', 
    'meta_value' => 'SWAP', 
    'FREE', 
    'WANTED',
    'meta_compare' => '!=',
    ...
)
```

I think this is what you want:

```
'meta_value' => array('SWAP', 'FREE', 'WANTED'),
```

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for looking at this. I have tried this but I dont think it has worked.

Comment: $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => '12', 
       'cat' => $cat_id,
       'posts_type' => 'post',
       'paged' => $paged, 
       'meta_key' => 'post_price', 
       'meta_value' => array('SWAP', 'FREE', 'WANTED'),
'meta_compare' => '!='

       ) );